# Angular 4 form values

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have an `input` fields that I built in the following way:

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let item of nutrients">
           <input matInput type="text" name="{{item.nutrientId}}_{{i}}" placeholder="{{item.nutrientName}} ({{item.nutrientMeasurement}})..." [(ngModel)]="product.productNutrient[i].amount" />
</mat-form-field>
```

The values are retrieved out of a list of this model:

```
constructor(
    public nutrientId?: number,
    public nutrientName?: string,
    public nutrientMeasurement?: string
)
```

I have another model `product_nutrient`:

```
constructor(
    public nutrientId?: number,
    public productId?: number,
    public amount?: number
)
```

This is included in my `product` model.

```
    constructor(
    public productId?: number,
    public productName?: string,
    public comments?: string,
    public manufacturerName?: string,
    public amount?: number,
    public measurement?: string,
    public isAdded?: boolean,
    public isConfirmed?: boolean,
    public productNutrient?: ProductNutrient[])
```

Below is my form:

```
<form name="addProductForm" #addProductForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addProduct(addProductForm)">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="text" name="productName" placeholder="Product naam..." required [(ngModel)]="product.productName" #productName="ngModel" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="text" name="productDescription" placeholder="Product beschrijving..." [(ngModel)]="product.productDescription" #productDescription="ngModel" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field >
        <input matInput type="text" name="manufacturerName" placeholder="Fabrikant naam..." [(ngModel)]="product.manufacturerName" #manufacurerName="ngModel" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="text" name="amount" placeholder="Hoeveelheid..." required [(ngModel)]="product.amount" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="text" name="measurement" placeholder="Meeteenheid..." required [(ngModel)]="product.measurement" #measurement="ngModel" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="text" name="comments" placeholder="Commentaar..." [(ngModel)]="product.comments" #comments="ngModel" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field *ngFor="let item of nutrients; let i = index">
           <input matInput type="text" name="{{item.nutrientId}}_{{i}}" placeholder="{{item.nutrientName}} ({{item.nutrientMeasurement}})..." [(ngModel)]="product.productNutrient[i].amount" />
        </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

What I would like is to fill `public productNutrient?: ProductNutrient[]` 
 in my `product` model with values from my looped input form, but I cannot get it to work.

I instantiated the array the following way in my `component.ts`

```
       this.product.productNutrient = new Array<ProductNutrient>();
```

But when I load the form I get the following erorr:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'amount' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to implement is a template-driven form in angular

- You only need ngModel to declare it to the form, not the [(ngModel)]
- If something is required as an input you can add the `required` directive
- Also for arrays, you'll want to iterate through an array, and add functionality to control that array, like addNutrient, removeNutrient. 
  This is a quick example that should get you going

Declare your model/interface, and be aware, suffix  `?` is only to indicate something is optional, so be cautious when using it. Also optional members can't be declared before non-optional

So outside your component you can add

```
export class Nutrient {
  constructor(
    public nutrientId?: number,
    public productId?: number,
    public amount?: number,
    public nutrientName?: string,
    public nutrientMeasurement?: string ) {}
};

export class Product {
  constructor(
  public productId?: number,
  public productName?: string,
  public comments?: string,
  public manufacturerName?: string,
  public amount?: number,
  public measurement?: string,
  public isAdded?: boolean,
  public isConfirmed?: boolean,
  public productNutrient?: Nutrient[]) {}
}
```

Inside your component you can

instantiate a product
Create an add/remove nutrient functions
as well as submit button ... . or addProduct

```
product: Product = new Product(
    0,
    '',
    '',
    '',
    0,
    '',
    false,
    false,
    []
    );


  addProduct(form: NgForm) {

    this.product = form.value;

    console.log(this.product);
  }

  onAddNutrient() {
    this.product.productNutrient.push(new Nutrient(0, 0, 0, '', '', ));
  }
  onRemoveNutrient() {
    this.product.productNutrient.pop();
  }
```

Then create your form in html

```
<form  #addProductForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addProduct(addProductForm)">

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="number" name="productId" placeholder="Product id..." required ngModel />
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="text" name="productName" placeholder="Product naam..." required ngModel />
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="text" name="productDescription" placeholder="Product beschrijving..."  ngModel />
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="text" name="manufacturerName" placeholder="Fabrikant naam..." ngModel />
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Hoeveelheid..." required ngModel />
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="number" name="measurement" placeholder="Meeteenheid..." required ngModel />
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="text" name="comments" placeholder="Commentaar..." ngModel  />
  </mat-form-field>

  <br>
  <div *ngFor="let nutrient of product.productNutrient; let i = index">
    <mat-form-field >
      <input matInput type="number" name="nutrientId" placeholder="Enter Nutrient Id..." ngModel />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field >
      <input matInput type="number" name="productId" placeholder="Enter Product Id..." ngModel />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field >
      <input matInput type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Enter Amount..." ngModel />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field >
      <input matInput type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Enter Nutrient Name.." ngModel />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field >
      <input matInput type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Enter Nutrient Measurement.." ngModel />
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>


  <button (click)="onAddNutrient()" type="button"> + </button>
  <button (click)="onRemoveNutrient()" type="button"> - </button>

  <br>

  <button class="btn btn-primary"  type="submit" > Submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't really get what you mean, I've updated my question above with the things I've tried.

Comment: I also would like to get the value of `name="{{item.nutrientId}}_{{i}}"` so how would I retrieve it with this method? As it isn't a default naming

Comment: Why do you need two models? you can make one model with several optional parameters